# jasmine-gem doesn't load jquery properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

My jasmine specs are running fine. But when I have to use jquery syntax like `$` I am getting following error :

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ in http://localhost:57132/__spec__/`

So, I added `gem "jasmine-jquery-rails"`

After `bundle install` still the same error.

Now I decided to add `jasmine-jquery` on the jasmine.yml file, but still the same error.

Then I decided to download `jasmine-jquery.js` manually and put that on `app/assets/javascripts` and add that to `jasmine.yml`. Then I get error on all specs.

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I think the order we load file is the issue here. But just couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using using the Jasmine gem yesterday, but after fighting with it for a while, I got it to work for me.

What you need is to get JQuery to register the $ handler. Just adding the JQuery library to the `src_files` in `yasmine.yml` doesn't seem to help with that.

What DID work for me was to include `assets/application.js` in jasmine.yml as the **first entry** under `src_files`:

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - '../vendor/javascripts/*.js'
  - 'javascript/**/*.js'
```

(I got my actual source files in the `javascript/` folder and use the `..vender/javascripts/` folder for third party libraries, this will be different for you.)

Make sure JQuery is required in `assets/javascripts/application.js` like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is pretty much how your `assets/javascripts/application.js` should look when you generate a new application via the `rails new` command line tool.

The `jasmine-jquery-rails` gem doesn't help with your issue because it adds additional testing functionality, not fundamental JQuery support.

Good success with getting Jasmine set up!